# Отложенная инициализация javascript-функций?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется несколько функций, внутри которых есть JQuery-зависимый код.

Проблема в том, что jQuery подключается в самом конце HTML-кода страницы, а функции написаны почти в начале страницы (внутри body) и поменять местами не получится (чужая и недоступная CMS)

**Есть ли возможность как-то отложить инициализацию этих функций** на время после загрузки (подключения) jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Понятия "инициализация функций" не существует.

Код внутри функции может зависеть от скрипта загруженного позже - постольку-поскольку функция не вызывается до загрузки этого второго скрипта.

Comment: получается ошибка: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined моя функция" - не потому что jQuery подключается после того как описана функция выше? функция сама по себе не вызывается, только при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @Enshtein Вероятно, библиотека jQuery не загрузилась (наберите в консоли браузера `$` или `jQuery`). Имеет смысл показать, как Вы это делаете.

Comment: с JQuery вроде бы всё нормально: https://prnt.sc/st8xf0

Comment: @Enshtein Постарайтесь создать в вопросе пример, демонстрирующий наблюдаемое явление.